# CLLocationManager - Monitoring regions vs. Significant Location Changes

Tags: ios, location, cllocationmanager

I am currently using significant location change updates to monitor whether or not the user has entered a particular area of interest (my definition of an area of interest is more broad than can be defined simply by geographic regions).  My requirements are that my app should be woken up periodically to check if the user is said defined area (if it is not currently running).

My question is: would registering for region updates (since I have a number of regions that are known to fit my area of interest), provide me with more updates than simply listening for all significant lcoation changes, or would they simply be duplicate updates?  The reason I ask this question is to clairify whether or not region monitoring is simply a filter on significant location change updates (since neither are documented as powering the GPS), or if region monitoring somehow is able to be more specific (maybe it powers the GPS, but with more specificity).  In particular, I would be interested to know if anyone has seen data or documentation on this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that you cannot 'wake up' your app. The app can continue running in the background to monitor location updates, but if the app is fully quit, it has to be re-opened by the user.

Comment: Sorry, not 'wake up', per say, but run in the background to display a notification if necessary.

Comment: That's not true, both options have the ability to be woken up from a terminated state to receive that location updates, even if closed by the user. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850088/will-ios-region-monitoring-call-didenterregion-on-my-app-if-my-app-is-in-a-termi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Region monitoring seems to pull from more specific location signal changes than the significant location change service. I say this because I've defined small regions (~100 m radius) that region monitoring picks up in the background, but that Significant location change does not. However please remember that the two events are triggered on different types of user actions.

Region monitoring - triggered on **boundary crossings** only. So a user must have two location update events on either side of the boundary. If you define large regions and the user walks around inside of them you will get **no** updates.

Significant location change - Seems to be triggered on the phone switching cell towers and the [Location Awareness](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10) docs seem to suggest that. Here is some [great data](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/07/22/iphone-background-gps-accurate-to-500-meters-not-enough-for-foot-traffic/) on general accuracy of these updates that suggests about 500 m between notification.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for that.  Fun fact: from experimentation, it looks like when the phone is asleep, it limits the frequency significant location updates (to about once every five - ten minutes), but doesn't do so for regions, which appears to explain why region monitoring updates are not simply a subset of significant location changes, but both rely on cell towers rather than powering the gps.  Also, I've noticed, I often get significant location change updates immediately after waking up my phone, if I've travelled while asleep.

Comment: so say I'm outside a region but then take the underground subway into a region. Would region monitoring not work b/c I did't cross a boundary?

Comment: Correct - until a location event is triggered inside a region it won't detect the crossing. However remember that location is not just GPS, my guess is cell + wifi could still detect that you are inside the region if available in the subway. Subways move fast so I'd suggest larger regions to prevent passing right through.

Comment: I'm guessing SignificantLocationChange wouldn't work well if user is in some remote place...because the cellTowers aren't that frequent. Right?