# Will iOS region monitoring call didEnterRegion on my app if my app is in a terminated state?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location

Will iOS region monitoring launch my app in the background if the user enters a region that was successfully being monitored for prior to the app being terminated?

I know that the significant change API will do so and will let me know at launch time via the inclusion of the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` key. If region monitoring will wake my app up out of a terminated state too, then what does the launch process look like? Is there a special key I should be looking for?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, see [Region Monitoring](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW1)

> In iOS, regions associated with your app are tracked at all times,
>   including when your app is not running. If a region boundary is
>   crossed while an app is not running, that app is relaunched into the
>   background to handle the event. Similarly, if the app is suspended
>   when the event occurs, it is woken up and given a short amount of time
>   (around 10 seconds) to handle the event.

Comment: Ok, that's great. When iOS relaunches my application, is there a special key that I should be looking for such as the significant change API's `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` or will iOS be launching my app from a terminated state the same way that a user would (i.e. other than being in the background my code will know no difference)?

Answer (score 4):

I have been searching for similar answer, but came across this: [Region monitoring in ios 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857034/region-monitoring-in-ios-7)

Seems like if the app is manually terminated by the user in iOS 7, location notifications will *not* wake the app to process it. Apple employee has commented here https://devforums.apple.com/thread/209302?tstart=0