# Region monitoring in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, location

I should use region monitoring in my iOs app for 6 and 7 version. And if my app was closed then system should open it. It works in iOS 6, but not works in iOS 7. I mean, System does not open my app if app was closed in ios 7.

About closing app, I mean, kill this app from memory.

I use this code:

```
manager = [CLLocationManager new];

manager.delegate = self;

[manager startUpdatingLocation];

if ([UIDevice isIOS7OrHigher]) {

    CLCircularRegion *reg = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(56.844947, 53.208852) radius:20.f identifier:@"reg14132"];

    [manager startMonitoringForRegion:reg];

    CLCircularRegion *reg1 = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( 56.844158,53.20913) radius:20.f identifier:@"reg14131232"];

    [manager startMonitoringForRegion:reg1];

} else {

    CLRegion *reg = [[CLRegion alloc]  initCircularRegionWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(56.844947, 53.208852) radius:20.f identifier:@"reg14132"];

    [manager startMonitoringForRegion:reg];

    CLRegion *reg1 = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( 56.844158,53.20913) radius:20.f identifier:@"reg14131232"];
    [manager startMonitoringForRegion:reg1];
}
```

And I use delegate methods for log. Also, I use this code for test

```
if (launchOptions) {
    UILocalNotification *note = [UILocalNotification new];
    note.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"launchOptions = %@", launchOptions];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:note];
}
```

Comment: You'll need to give more details about your issue, a sample of your region monitoring and backgrounding code.

Comment: @alex_izh Please use `code` style for the code instead of a `quote` style, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is now the expected behaviour starting with iOS7. In iOS6 and earlier, even if you manually killed the app from the app-switcher, you would still get a notification when the user entered/exited a region. This behaviour has **changed** with iOS7. If the user has killed the app from the app-switcher, i.e. by swiping up on your app, then they will no longer receive any location-based notifications, including region monitoring notifications. This was confirmed by an Apple Employee in the official Apple developer forums - [link here](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/209302?tstart=0).

The only solution provided by Apple Dev was "Please file bug reports if this change is problematic for you or you would like to see something different."

I personally think this was a terrible decision, as it defeats the purpose of background notifications. You will have to advise your users upgrading from iOS6, as they will continue to expect similar functionality and this change has not been documented anywhere.

**EDIT**: As @herz below has pointed out, starting in iOS 7.1, the background monitoring functionality has reverted to how it was in iOS 6. Regions will be monitored and your app will receive notifications even when it is killed from the app switcher.

Comment: I disagree that this was a terrible decision. If the user force-quit your app then it's probably because he doesn't want to have anything to do with it anymore (but doesn't want to delete it).

Comment: I think it all changed again in iOS 7.1 because I now get notifications when the app is not in the tray ...

Comment: @HerzRod, are you sure that ios7.1 is OK?

Comment: Yes, locationManager:didEnterRegion: gets called and your application goes to the background for 5 seconds where you can now request more time via beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: and make server calls or whatever you need.

Comment: The weird thing is, I have audio that ducks other audio and plays in the background when my app is running in the background when it triggers a region, but lately it seems the that the app (even when swipe closed) ducks other audio, (doesn't play the audio) and then unducks it, like it was about to play music but then it doesn't.... very weird; and not good, as one of my users has already complained about this.... When the app is swipe closed the region arrow is still there, and the regions are definitely still being monitored. This is still a bug (iOS 7.1.x)

Comment: Is this still the case now with iOS 9?  Will region monitoring still wake up the terminated app?

Comment: As of iOS10 the behavior of force-quit app is: didEnterRegion is called steadily as soon as the app inside the region. Location manager's delegate methods are called during ~5 seconds each time the screen is lit up (or unlocked).