# Geofencing when App is killed by user in iOS7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c

In iOS7.1 , when a user kills an app , does the geofencing still works?

If geofencing is detecting the device is entering or exiting the region, can it trigger a local notification (even when the user has killed the app ) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will iOS region monitoring call didEnterRegion on my app if my app is in a terminated state?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850088/will-ios-region-monitoring-call-didenterregion-on-my-app-if-my-app-is-in-a-termi)

Answer (score 1):

you GeoFencing still works it works like push notification / or passbook same thing it will still generate notification for your app. bellow function will fire even if app is not running in background.

```
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSString *event = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"didExitRegion %@ at %@",         region.identifier, [NSDate date]];
[self updateWithEvent:event];
     //implement local notification:    
UIApplication *app                = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

if (notification == nil)
    return;
notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Did You Lock Your House?"];
notification.alertAction = @"Lock House";
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName; 
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
[app presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];

[notification release];

}
```

Comment: If the user explicitly kills the app from the task screen, then you will no longer receive region notifications - This is changed behaviour in 7.x - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850088/will-ios-region-monitoring-call-didenterregion-on-my-app-if-my-app-is-in-a-termi

Comment: @Paulw11 I am agree 100% but it's all change in ios 7.1 now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857034/region-monitoring-in-ios-7 read last line

Comment: This thread https://devforums.apple.com/thread/221825?tstart=0 seems to indicate that the behaviour has changed again - no confirmation from Apple in the thread though

Comment: I tried something very similiar to m-farhan's answer, but it does not wake up when the app is killed by user (it works when it's in background). any suggestions?